User Mode Networking between multiple Guests in Qemu
Is it possible in QEMU to create a user mode netdev (so no tap device or similiar) that multiple guests can use to communicate with each other?
In the documentation I've seen the netdev=socket,connect= and netdev=socket,listen= devices but those only work between one pair of guests. I want a bus that multiple guests can share.
It seems that -netdev socket,mcast= might be able to achieve that, but I do not know how to correctly setup the guests. I find the documentation partially understandable (what is localaddr for example?). I've used the first example from https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/qemu-manpage.html
# launch one QEMU instance
qemu-system-x86_64 linux.img \
                 -device e1000,netdev=n1,mac=52:54:00:12:34:56 \
                 -netdev socket,id=n1,mcast=230.0.0.1:1234
# launch another QEMU instance on same "bus"
qemu-system-x86_64 linux.img \
                 -device e1000,netdev=n2,mac=52:54:00:12:34:57 \
                 -netdev socket,id=n2,mcast=230.0.0.1:1234
# launch yet another QEMU instance on same "bus"
qemu-system-x86_64 linux.img \
                 -device e1000,netdev=n3,mac=52:54:00:12:34:58 \
                 -netdev socket,id=n3,mcast=230.0.0.1:1234

but when giving guests an IP on that interface they seem seem to be unable to communicate with each other. (tried both pings and HTTP requests). How to correctly setup such an configuration?
